# VOIP implementation in iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip

I have to implement VOIP in iPhone app,which is the best way of performing this.
If you have any idea please share with me or give me some pointer from where i can explore and get some better solution.
Thanks

Comment: [Stackoverflow is not a recommendation engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/102937).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have iPhone Voip app. Could you please let me know what will be the purpose or functionality do you want to have in this app.

If you want to make calls using VoIP uses SIP(session initiation protocol) for communication to VoIP tor VoIP to PSTN. Follow the below URL for iPhone VoIP Client.

http://code.google.com/p/siphon

Get the source code and compiled it using the instructions from below URL;

http://code.google.com/p/siphon/wiki/Compilation

For VoIP Stack Please visit www.pjsip.org.

Answer (score 0):

Use pjsip. It's a SIP library written in C.  pjsip uses GPL license.

You may find [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html) to do so.